# Как сделать отмену выполнения FSM aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

В боте есть много функций, которые являются состояниями. Как сделать отмену выполнения состояний?
Я понимаю, что можно просто в каждой функции написать что-то вроде:

```
if message.text == '/cancel':
    await message.answer('действие отменено')
    await state.finish()
    return
```

но нельзя ли создать какую-то универсальную функцию, которая бы при команде /cancel делала state.finish()?

Заранее спасибо за помощь и извиняюсь если плохо объяснил, задавайте любые вопросы, всё уточню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете добавить такой хэндлер:

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Действие отменено')
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Cпасибо! Можно ли сделать так, чтобы если пользователь написал /cancel просто так, то бот ответил "нечего отменять"?